# C++ Parsing a CSV file into vector of vectors: Loosing string 1st character

Tags: c++, string, file, csv, vector

I am reading a CSV file into vector of string vectors. I have written code below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream mesh;
    mesh.open("mesh_reference.csv");

    vector<vector<string> > point_coordinates;
    string line, word;

    while (getline(mesh,line))
    {
        stringstream ss(line);
        vector<string> row;
        while (getline(ss, word, ','))
        {
            row.push_back(word);
        }
        point_coordinates.push_back(row);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<point_coordinates.size(); i++) 
    {
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
            cout<<point_coordinates[i][j]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I print out the vector of vectors, I see that I am loosing the first character of Element at 0 position in the vector row. Basically, `point_coordinates[0][0]` is displaying 0.0001 while the string is supposed to be -0.0001. I am not able to understand the reason for the same. Kindly help.

A typical output line is

```
 .0131 -0.019430324 0.051801
```

Whereas the CSV data is

```
0.0131,-0.019430324,0.051801
```

**SAMPLE CSV DATA FROM FILE**

```
    NODES__X,NODES__Y,NODES__Z
    0.0131,-0.019430324,0.051801
    0.0131,-0.019430324,0.06699588
    0.0131,-0.018630324,0.06699588
    0.0131,-0.018630324,0.051801
    0.0131,-0.017630324,0.050801
    0.0131,-0.017630324,0.050001
    0.0149,-0.017630324,0.050001
    0.0149,-0.019430324,0.051801
```

Comment: There is no obvious problem with the shown code, therefore the problem must be in the code that's not shown. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] gives you direction for formatting any code that you include in your question as a [mre], otherwise nobody will be able to help you. You need to [edit], and include everything anyone needs (should be at most a few dozen lines or so, including any sample input), that anyone cut-and-paste and reproduce your problem themselves. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, Thanks for the suggestion, I have edited the code to form a complete program. Sample CSV data is also provided.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with posted code and data. Are you sure you are opening the data file you think you are opening? Try deleting it and running the program again.

Comment: Yes @NeilButterworth. If I add this line: `cout<<row[0]<<" "<<row[1]<<" "<<row[2]<<endl;` after row.pushback loop, I am getting the first character in the output. However, the resultant vector is becoming the issue, the output has a blank one character space at the left edge of output.

Comment: Take a look at the code in your comment, and the code in your program. There's something missing. Specifically `std::endl`. You are seeing obvious artifacts of output wrapping from one line to the next one.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, Thanks for solving my mystery. Tried to bite of too much learning curve and did not see small things. Just used endl everywhere. Should I delete this question? Not of any value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the problem is already solved, I would like to show you a solution using some modern C++ algorithms and eliminating minor issues.

- Do not use `using namespace std;`. You should not do this
- Ne need for a separate file.open. The `std::ifstream` constructor will open the file for you. And the destructor will close it
- Check if the file could be opened. The `ifstreams` `!` operator is overloaded. So you can do a boolean check
- Do not use `int` in for loops where you compare against `.size()`. Use ````size_t instead
- Always initialize all variables, even if there is an assignement in the next line
- For tokenizing you should use `std::sregex_token_iterator`. It has exactly been designed for this purpose
- In modern C++ you are encouraged to use algorithms

Please see an improved version of your code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>

const std::regex comma(",");

int main()
{
    // Open source file.
    std::ifstream mesh("r:\\mesh_reference.csv");

    // Here we will store the result
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> point_coordinates;

    // We want to read all lines of the file
    std::string line{};
    while (mesh && getline(mesh, line)) {
        // Tokenize the line and store result in vector. Use range constructor of std::vector
        std::vector<std::string> row{ std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(),line.end(),comma,-1), std::sregex_token_iterator() };
        point_coordinates.push_back(row);
    }
    // Print result. Go through all lines and then copy line elements to std::cout
    std::for_each(point_coordinates.begin(), point_coordinates.end(), [](std::vector<std::string> & vs) {
        std::copy(vs.begin(), vs.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " ")); std::cout << "\n"; });

    return 0;
}
```

Please consider, if you may want to use such an approach in the future

Comment: All my coding styles are outright borrowed from C. I hardly know much C++. Your solution does it so elegantly, while I struggled for hours to get my solution code working. Thanks for guiding with modern and crisp version of my code. Will use this further.